# Search all public resources in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-search

I want to know how to find all public resources in Google Drive that I can access. My Google account is from my company and I would like to look for public resources like presentations, etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved: search using `source:domain`